# Guard against execution of PHPUnit bootstrap file

Tags: php, security, phpunit

I want to make sure the code in my PHPUnit bootstrap file does not get executed via the web in case the server is on is not properly configured. Does PHPUnit define some constant that can be used in the bootstrap to ensure it is not getting invoked correctly? Is there some other good way of getting around this potential attack vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use php_sapi_name(). It will return "cli" if invoked from the command line. If it returns something else, the bootstrap file should refuse to execute.